# How to unpivot with BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Good evening lads,
I'm currently having issues with this table:

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvbad.png)

Here i want to turn it into something like this:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC7jX.png)

I tried with this query but seems it didnt work:

SELECT
item_nbr,
cid

FROM
db.forecast

unpivot (

WM_YR_WK For item_nbr in (Fcst_Ttl_Curr    ,
Fcst_Ttl_01       ,
Fcst_Ttl_02       ,
Fcst_Ttl_03       ,
Fcst_Ttl_04       ,
Fcst_Ttl_05       ,
Fcst_Ttl_06       ,
Fcst_Ttl_07       ,
Fcst_Ttl_08       ,
Fcst_Ttl_09       ,
Fcst_Ttl_10       ,
Fcst_Ttl_11       ,
Fcst_Ttl_12       ,
Fcst_Ttl_13       ,
Fcst_Ttl_14       ,
Fcst_Ttl_15       ,
Fcst_Ttl_16   )

) as Forecast

WHERE

CAST (Dept_Nbr AS STRING) IN ('01')
AND team LIKE ('%Groseries%')
and squad like ('%Cheese%')
anD (CAST(DEPT_NBR AS STRING)||TRIM(CAST(CATEGORY_NBR AS STRING)))  IN ('0110','0111','0112')

Group By
1,2,3

I hope someone can help us, thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I believe you should add some simple code that illustrates the problem. Right now, it is hard to understand what's the error you get, and most of us don't have time to punch mock-data for a large number of columns. BR